Issue login route with Render deploy for PostgresSQL database and Web Service
I am fairly new to coding and I am having a problem with a Web Service and Postgres SQL database that I have deployed to render.
I have created an Postgres SQL database, and Web Service. The web service will act as a server back end for a React App that I have not deployed yet. I am testing the server and the database using postman and most of the routes seem to be working fine, however I am having trouble following the sign in route.
I am using a passport local strategy, and the sql databse as a session store. From adding console.log’s it seems that retrieving the user details from the database to compare to the body of the request works fine, however I have an issue when the session is needed to be created I get the following error message: AggregateError [ECONNREFUSED].
I have put the relevant code below:
SERVER SETUP:
// set up imports
const express = require('express');
require('dotenv').config();
const passport = require('passport');
const initializePassport = require('./controllers/auth.js');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const cors = require('cors');
const session = require('express-session');
const { DB, SS } =require('./config');

//route imports
const { registerRouter, signinRouter, logoutRouter, orderRouter, userRouter, checkRouter } = require('./routes/userRoute.js');
const { productRouter } = require('./routes/productRoute.js');
const { cartRouter } = require('./routes/cartRoute.js');

//server setup
const app = express();

app.set('trust proxy', 1)

// Used for testing to make sure server / express app is running.
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send('<h1>Hello Kiernan</h1>');
});

app.use(cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'OPTIONS', 'DELETE', 'HEAD'],
    credentials: true,
}));
app.use(helmet());
const pgSession = require('connect-pg-simple')(session);
const { PORT } =require('./config');
const port = PORT || 3001;
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


const options = {
    user: DB.DB_USER, 
    host: DB.DB_HOST,
    database: DB.DB_DATABASE,
    password: DB.DB_PASSWORD,
    port: DB.DB_PORT,
    createDatabaseTable: true,
    createTableIfMissing: true
};

console.log(options);

const sessionStore = new pgSession(options);

app.use(session({
    name: SS.SS_SESS_NAME,
    resave: false, 
    saveUninitialized: false, 
    store: sessionStore,
    secret: SS.SS_SESS_SECRET,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: Number(SS.SS_SESS_LIFETIME),
        sameSite: 'lax', 
        secure: true,
        domain: "localhost",
        httpOnly: true,
        hostOnly: false,
    } 
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

initializePassport(passport);

//configuration to allow the front end to store cookies created on the server:
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", http://localhost:3000); 
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true); // allows cookie to be sent
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, HEAD, DELETE"); // you must specify the methods used with credentials. "*" will not work. 
    next();
});

//route for users
app.use('/api/users/register', registerRouter);
app.use('/api/users/signin', signinRouter);
app.use('/api/users/logout', logoutRouter);
app.use('/api/users/orders', orderRouter);
app.use('/api/users/details', userRouter);
app.use('/api/users/check-session', checkRouter);

//route for products
app.use('/api/products', productRouter);

//route for cart
app.use('/api/cart', cartRouter)

//app.listen
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Your server is listening on port: ${port}`);
});

SIGN IN ROUTE:
const signinRouter = express.Router();
signinRouter.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('local', async (err, user, info) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
        }
    
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(401).json ({ message: info.message, check: 'this is the error I am getting today' });
        }
        req.login(user, (loginErr) => {
            if (loginErr) {
                return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Login Error', msg: loginErr });
            }
            return res.status(200).json({ user }); 
        });
    }) (req, res, next);
});

LOCAL STRATEGY:
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const pool = require('../db/index');

module.exports = (passport) => {
    const query = async (queryString, params) => {
        return await pool.query(queryString, params);
    };

    passport.use(
        new LocalStrategy ( async ( username, password, done) => {
            try {
                const querySchema = { name: 'user', email: `${username}`};
                const queryString = `SELECT * FROM user_customer WHERE email = $1`;
                const userResult = await query(queryString, [querySchema.email]);

                if (userResult.rows.length === 0 ) {
                    return done(null, false, { message: 'User not found' });
                }

                const foundUser = userResult.rows[0];

                console.log('This is the found user from auth.js', foundUser)

                const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, foundUser.password);
                if (isMatch) {
                    return done(null, { //rather than an object here, does it just need to say 'user' after null?
                        id: foundUser.id,
                        email: foundUser.email,
                        firstName: foundUser.first_name,
                        lastName: foundUser.last_name
                    });
                } else {
                    return done(null, false, {message: 'Incorrect password '});
                }
            } catch (err) {
                console.error('Error during authentication. ' + err);
                return done(err);
            }
        })
    );

    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
        try {
            const userResult = await query('SELECT * FROM user_customer WHERE id = $1',
                [id]
            );
            if (userResult.rows.length === 0) {
                return done(new Error('User not found'));
            } return done(null, userResult.rows[0].id);
        } catch(err) {
            done(err);
        }
    });
};

I am expecting when the request is made via postman with the correct details in the body, for those to be checked and confirmed correct, a session to be created, details stored in the session store and the session cookie sent back in the response.
I have read through as many articles as I can to see if I can find an answer. I have tried various bug fixing to find the route of the issue. I can see that when the login route is called the server can access details in the database to retrieve user details, and in the other routes (GET POST) seem to work fine. I am sure that the issue comes when the server tried to create the session.
The error itself is visible on the body of the response in postman which looks as follows:
{
"error": "Login Error",
"msg": {
"code": "ECONNREFUSED"
}
}
You can also see it in the log in Render:
Failed to prune sessions: AggregateError [ECONNREFUSED]: 
    at /opt/render/project/src/node_modules/pg-pool/index.js:45:11
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async PGStore._asyncQuery (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/connect-pg-simple/index.js:321:21)
    at async PGStore._rawEnsureSessionStoreTable (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/connect-pg-simple/index.js:176:19)
    at async PGStore._asyncQuery (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/connect-pg-simple/index.js:314:7) {
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  [errors]: [
    Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:5432
        at createConnectionError (node:net:1647:14)
        at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1677:16) {
      errno: -111,
      code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
      syscall: 'connect',
      address: '::1',
      port: 5432
    }

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Many Thanks.
